# Geometric interpretation of an underdetermined system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, geometric-interpretation

I am having a difficult time connecting different parts of a geometric interpretation of an underdetermined system of equations.

Given the matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$

I can interpret it as each column being a vector in 2-dimensional space in which case I can express any vector on that plane with the first and second column, since the third one is a linear combination of the first two.

I can also interpret the matrix as the equations of the planes

$$ \begin{aligned} 2x+y+3z&=0 \\ x+2y+3z&=0 \end{aligned}$$ and the solution for those equations being the line that is the intersection between the two planes. This gets me a line instead of a whole plane as above.

If I see it as the coefficient matrix for a linear transformation, then to use it I would have to provide a vector in 3D-space, and the output would land in plane in 3D-space.

If I am asked to provide the geometric interpretation of the above matrix, which of these would be correct? Is there some relation between them that I am not seeing? Does the question require more context to be answered?

Comment: Gilbert Strang calls them the "column picture" and "row picture", if I properly recall.  Are you acquainted with his work?

Comment: Not really, but it sounds like they are distinct interpretations then. Searching for that led me to this question, which formulated it much more eloquently than I did. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348233/reconciling-the-column-and-the-row-pictures-for-matrices. Thank you!